# Liberty Kernel (Java 6 Web Profile) & Deltaspike trouble

Tags: websphere-liberty

my setup consists of WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.9 Kernel, JDK 1.8.0_74, Eclipse Mars with Liberty Tools, on Windows 7 64 Bit.

I've got a simple Maven project (Code on GitHub: [deltaspike-windowscope](https://github.com/selste/deltaspike/tree/HEAD/deltaspike-windowscope)), a Facelet and a WindowScoped Bean.
When i start Liberty (with resources from the Eclipse workspace) warnings are shown in the Console:

> [WARNUNG ] Could NOT lazily initialize session context because NO active request context
>   [WARNUNG ]

Additionally there are logs in the ffdc directory, the summary file containing

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError com.ibm.ws.webbeans.impl.scanner.LibertyScannerService.loadBeanClasses 553

The start of the stacktrace looks like this:

> Exception = java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>   Source = com.ibm.ws.webbeans.impl.scanner.LibertyScannerService.loadBeanClasses
>   probeid = 553
>   Stack Dump = java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/faces/lifecycle/LifecycleWrapper
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.definePackageAndClass(AppClassLoader.java:327)
>       at com.ibm.ws.classloading.internal.AppClassLoader.findClass(AppClassLoader.java:269)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)

The code runs just fine on Wildfly (8 to 10), TomEE 1.7.3 and WebSphere 8.0, i haven't tried WebSphere 8.5 yet.

Any ideas what's going on here - suggestions highly appreciated?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know what Liberty features are provisioned at startup? I'm wondering if jsf-2.2 is being included.

Comment: The Java 6 Web Profile is enabled, that includes CDI 1.0, JPA 2.0 and JSF 2.0, plus a load of other stuff like JDBC - i'd have to check the server.xml for a complete list (including dependent features)

Comment: Are there other symptoms or logs that may indicate the problem? The ClassDefNotFound error may not prevent the application from functioning. I believe that is being shown because LifecycleWrapper is a JSF2.2 class and Java 6 Web Profile includes JSF2.0. Is there functional issue beyond the FFDC?

Answer (score 0):

Just confirm that the ffdc you observed will not prevent the application from functioning. What errors did you get?

Comment: But of course these FFDC errors shouldn't occur in the first place. Problem is, as soon as i add JPA (really basic BCE pattern, nothing fancy) the application doesn't even start up anymore. I'll provide a sample on Monday and publish the code on GitHub, i'm not at the office right now.

Comment: Just as additional background: We got one application running with Deltaspike 1.5.4 on WebSphere 8.0 - on startup a couple of info messages are displayed, but no warnings or errors. So far i haven't been able to get the exact same application running on WebSphere Liberty ... so i started 'from scratch' - haven't gotten far, sadly.

Comment: Ok, just to get to the real issue - new branch called 'feature_JPA' on GitHub, added the JPA project facet, a persistence.xml, OpenJPA dependency (provided), a entity and a simple stateless session bean: `@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PlayerService implements Serializable {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "deltaspike-windowscope")
 EntityManager entityManager;

 public PlayerService() {}
}` that does nothing. Right after adding this bean the application doesn't start up anymore.

Comment: I've added the FFDC logs as well: [https://github.com/selste/deltaspike/blob/feature_JPA/deltaspike-windowscope/src/test/resources/liberty/logs/messages.log]

Comment: The - i think - relevant entries during startup: `[11.04.16 08:12:27:624 MESZ] 00000019 org.apache.webbeans.context.LibertyContextsService           W Could NOT lazily initialize session context because NO active request context
[11.04.16 08:12:27:633 MESZ] 00000019 org.apache.webbeans.component.ManagedBean                    E Bei der Injektion von Java-EE-Ressourcen f�r die Beaninstanz ist ein Fehler aufgetreten: [org.apache.deltaspike.core.impl.scope.window.WindowIdHolder@72ea2c1e]`

Comment: Just for laughs i replaced DeltaSpike with CODI, the changes are pretty minimal, and Liberty starts up without any complaints whatsoever.

Comment: The error suggests there is a resource injection failure and the runtime should not throw NullPointerException. Please contact IBM support.